# Postgres list dynamic partitioning

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to make dynamic partitions in Postgres.
What am I trying to achieve:
I will have `tableA` that will have a lot of data and will have a column with `some_id` which will be heavily used in `where` statement.
So, my plan is to have partition by list with `some_id` value.
How to achieve dynamic partitioning, So when new id is inserted partition is dynamically created?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that in PostgreSQL currently.

Comment: Thanks. What about a bit hardcoding with trigger? Would that be considered as good practice?

Comment: I tried, and it doesn't work. Basically, a trigger that is run from an action on a table cannot modify the table's definition.

Answer (score 0):

The best possible way to do it currently is through code.
Since trigger cannot change table definition the best approach would be to do execute a statement after through a backend after insert.